# Using j-fischer error logging framework, Log Monitor not showing whole log data in namespace org

Tags: error, framework

When I am using the log monitor in the developer org , the log data created is fine and completed. But when i am using log monitor in a namespace Org , the log data is not coming as whole. The script I am running is as follows :

```
rflib_Logger LOGGER = rflib_LoggerUtil.getFactory().createLogger('Demo class');
rflib_LogTimer logtimer = rflib_LoggerUtil.startLogTimer(LOGGER,300,'Handling Demo class');

try {
  LOGGER.info('TRYING FINDING INPUT VALUES');
  LOGGER.warn('Values and fields missing');
}
catch(Exception e) {
  LOGGER.error('Anonymous error occured',e);
}

logtimer.done();
```

I am attaching screenshots for both , if anyone has solution for it , please help.
[image: Log monitor in namespace org]

[image: Log monitor in developer org]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the namespace Org you need to use the org namespace prefix for all custom fields of the platform event.

For the rflibLogEventViewer component

```
<lightning-formatted-text value={logEvent.Log_Messages__c}>
```

Need to update like:

```
<lightning-formatted-text value={logEvent.namespaceprefix__Log_Messages__c}>
```

Comment: Yes. This worked.